# Как обновить определенную строку БД

Tags: java, android

Использую *MySql*, как *УБД*. Нужно обновить определенную строку *(допустим строка с id 55)*. Как можно её обновить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android sqlite update row](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20sqlite%20update%20row)

И вот этому ответу с [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527/3212712)

Надо так:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Field1","Bob"); //These Fields should be your String values of actual column names
cv.put("Field2","19");
cv.put("Field2","Male");

myDB.update(TableName, cv, "_id="+id, null);
```

Comment: Я же указал Mysql

Comment: @elik, ну да, php скрипт подойдёт

Answer (score 1):

В Андроиде используют LiteSQL

```
//Создаем экземпляр класса Базы Данных (открытую для чтения и записи)
SQLiteDatabase database = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
//Создадим объект класса ДЛЯ ДОБАВЛЕНИЯ НОВЫХ СТРОК В ТАБЛИЦУ
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//Добавляем новое значение (если строка состоит из 5 колонок, то для каждой такая строка)
contentValues.put(НАЗВАНИЕ КОЛОНКИ, info);
//Вызываем метод update (Имя Таблицы, обновленный контент, Строка условия и массив аргументов для строки условия)
database.update(TABLEMAIN_NAME, contentValues, DBHelper.MAIN_TABLE_ID + "= ?", new String[]{id});
//или та же строчка что выше, но по другому написана
database.update(TABLEMAIN_NAME, contentValues, TABLE_ID " = " + id, null);
```

Comment: Спасибо с ней проблем нет у меня с sql проблема

Comment: Просто в вопросе есть тег android я и подумал что LiteSQL, хотя особой разницы нет, SQL и там и там используют. 

Последнюю строчку можно еще так написать:
        database.update(TABLEMAIN_NAME, contentValues, TABLE_ID " = " + id, null);

Comment: mysql точнее блин что со снолј )

Comment: В любом случае мой ответ подходит :) и подробно расписан, думаю проблем с понимание не должно быть.